A place somewhere in Europe?

Add another circle, a rectangle and an oval to the circle shown above and turn it into a public place where hundreds of people come and go every day
Note, this has been asked before but I am not convinced by the accepted answer

Welcome to puzzle SE. If it has been asked before, could you add a link?

This is a duplicate of : A place somewhere in Europe. Reposting a question provides no purpose, if you are unsure of the previous answer, you should comment there instead

I have tried commenting there but unfortunately it wasn't allowed. Perhaps you could try for me. The accepted answer is not applicable as there is no "an" in the given answer

I think that's just a parsing issue. You're parsing the instructions as "add 'an oval'", when they should be parsed as "add an 'oval'", if that makes sense.

There's also no "another" in the answer. Some words are simply serving grammatical functions.

"Another", however is useful as there is already one circle. "An" is just there for no real reason. All words matter for all meanings
